# Cross filters in plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly, interactive, crossfilter

I'm interested in creating offline interactive charts using plotly in python, what I want to achieve is applying cross filters in data visualization,  similar to what we do when doing online shopping, by clicking on boxes like 'size: M','color: black','long-sleeve','sweater' to filter what we want.

Let's say my data has features A,B,C,D,E,F....
I want to plot the relations between B and E, also I want to apply filters to select those with subclass A1 from A, subclass C3 from C, etc...

I tried some search but didn't find what I want, I saw that I can upload my csv to plotly's online workspace Chart Studio, but I only want to do it in offline mode. Anyone knows if what I describe above is doable at this moment in plotly?

Any help or alternative suggestion is appreciated! :)

Comment: How is your data stored? Are you using dataframes? You should include a sample of your data as well as your desired output in your post. What are you specifically having troubles with?

Comment: yes I'm using dataframes, I know how to do filtering in data but was wondering if I can use interactive charts to filter&visualize them with multiple filters selected, like selecting size and color when doing online shopping. I don't have a specific trouble yet, was looking for a direction...

Comment: Have you looked into Dash?